# PHP merge associative arrays by replacing same keys and adding new

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of variable size structured like this (`categories` is only one of the keys inside `data`):

```
print_r($json[123]["data"]["categories"]);
array(
  array(
    'id' => '2',
    'description' => 'Single-player'
  ),
  array(
    'id' => '1',
    'description' => 'Multi-player'
  ),
  array(
    'id' => '9',
    'description' => 'Co-op'
  ),
  array(
    'id' => '22',
    'description' => 'Steam Achievements'
  ),
  array(
    'id' => '28',
    'description' => 'Full controller support'
  )
)

print_r($json[456]["data"]["categories"]);
array(
  array(
    'id' => '21',
    'description' => 'Downloadable Content'
  ),
  array(
    'id' => '1',
    'description' => 'Multi-player'
  )
)
```

Now, I want to merge these sub-arrays (they can be in variable number) and have all keys added and replaced. I've tried array_merge but it replaces the keys without adding new ones.
In this case I need to obtain this array:

```
print_r($merged["data"]["categories"]);
array(
  array(
    'id' => '2',
    'description' => 'Single-player'
  ),
  array(
    'id' => '1',
    'description' => 'Multi-player'
  ),
  array(
    'id' => '9',
    'description' => 'Co-op'
  ),
  array(
    'id' => '22',
    'description' => 'Steam Achievements'
  ),
  array(
    'id' => '28',
    'description' => 'Full controller support'
  ),
  array(
    'id' => '21',
    'description' => 'Downloadable Content'
  )
)
```

Any help?

**Edit:**
I think I didn't expressed myself well enough. `$json[$id]["data"]` has multiple keys I want to merge (`categories` is just an example). Also the number of `$json[$id]` keys is variable
**Edit2:**
The arrays can have duplicate values, and the depth of the keys can be variable. I need to get something like `array_merge_recursive()` but with same values replaced.
**Edit3:**
This is the current array. http://pastebin.com/7x7KaAVM I need to merge all keys that have sub-arrays

Comment: The order of arguments to array_merge() makes a difference: `array_merge($json[123]["data"]["categories"],$json[456]["data"]["categories"])` !== `array_merge($json[456]["data"]["categories"],$json[123]["data"]["categories"])`

Comment: you can start creating new array from these two result and print that new one as $newarry = array();
$newarry[] = $json[123]["data"]["categories"];
$newarry[] = $json[456]["data"]["categories"];

Comment: @user2706194 Question updated

Comment: $newarry[] = $json[$id]["data"]["categories"];
this will use all this listing in single array

Answer (score 0):

**Try this** . To generalize I have added some more arrays.

```
<?php
    $merged_array = array();
    $final_array = array();
    $json[123]["data"]["categories"] = array(
                                            array(
                                              'id' => '2',
                                              'description' => 'Single-player'
                                            ),
                                            array(
                                              'id' => '1',
                                              'description' => 'Multi-player'
                                            ),
                                            array(
                                              'id' => '9',
                                              'description' => 'Co-op'
                                            ),
                                            array(
                                              'id' => '22',
                                              'description' => 'Steam Achievements'
                                            ),
                                            array(
                                              'id' => '28',
                                              'description' => 'Full controller support'
                                            )
                                          );
    $json[456]["data"]["categories"] = array(
                                            array(
                                              'id' => '21',
                                              'description' => 'Downloadable Content'
                                            )
                                          );
    $json[786]["data"]["categories"] = array(
                                            array(
                                              'id' => '31',
                                              'description' => 'Downloadable Content'
                                            )
                                          );
    $json[058]["data"]["categories"] = array(
                                            array(
                                              'id' => '41',
                                              'description' => 'Downloadable Content'
                                            )
                                          );

    foreach($json as $key=>$value){
        array_push($merged_array,$json[$key]["data"]["categories"]);      
    }

    foreach($merged_array as $value){
        foreach($value as $val){
            array_push($final_array,$val);      
        }
    }
    print_r($final_array);

?>
```

**RESULT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [description] => Single-player
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [description] => Multi-player
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [description] => Co-op
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 22
            [description] => Steam Achievements
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 28
            [description] => Full controller support
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21
            [description] => Downloadable Content
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 31
            [description] => Downloadable Content
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 41
            [description] => Downloadable Content
        )

)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I got wrong one more time, please see my edited question.

Comment: Then can you provide the sample arrays of atleast 3 or 4 diff categories, i mean the different key depth??

Comment: I can see a lot of arrays here. Among these which are the ones you need to merger together? Give me the keys?? Or the categories only??

Comment: "categories", "developers", "publishers", "genres"

Comment: Yes. If there's a structure I can re-use if in future I'll need some others key, it would be better

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code:**

```
$json = array(
'123' => array('data' => array('categories' => array(
        array(
            'id' => '2',
            'description' => 'Single-player'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => '1',
            'description' => 'Multi-player'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => '9',
            'description' => 'Co-op'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => '22',
            'description' => 'Steam Achievements'
        ),
        array(
            'id' => '28',
            'description' => 'Full controller support'
        )
    ))
              ),
'456' => array('data' => array('categories' => array(
        array(
            'id' => '21',
            'description' => 'Downloadable Content'
            )
        ))
       ),
);

//print_r($json);

$merged = array();
foreach($json as $j1)
{
    foreach($j1 as $j2)
    {
        foreach($j2 as $key => $j3)
        {
            foreach($j3 as $j4)
            {
                $merged[$key][] = $j4;
            }
        }
    }
}

print_r($merged);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [categories] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [description] => Single-player
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [description] => Multi-player
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 9
                    [description] => Co-op
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 22
                    [description] => Steam Achievements
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 28
                    [description] => Full controller support
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 21
                    [description] => Downloadable Content
                )

        )

)
```

**Demo:**

http://3v4l.org/X61bE#v430

Comment: I'm sorry, I got wrong one more time, please see my edited question.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: And yes, the above code can handle the depth of keys.